# Do I need to use locks when simply assigning variables?

Tags: c#, multithreading

When multithreading I know that I need to lock variables if doing things like adding and item to a list etc or I would get a cross thread exception. But do I need to lock them when just assigning variables? I don't mind about if a thread getting an old instance of the variable - I just don't want it to error. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
    public void Run()
    {
        var thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test));
        var thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test));
        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();
    }

    private static int _test;

    private void Test()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _test += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "error"?

Comment: `+=` is a *read* and *assignment* (non-atomic together).

Comment: Sorry - I meant read and assign. Yes that's what I was trying to demonstrate with the +=

Comment: If just one thread (a) reads the variable, and the (b) writes a new value to the variable (the new value being one greater than what was read), it works fine. But with two threads, it sometimes goes wrong. For if thread one first (a1) reads the variable, and reads `42`, and another thread, two, immediately after (a2) also reads `42`. Then one of the threads (b1) overwrites the variable with `43`, and finally the other thread overwrites (b2) with `43` as well. So the variable was attempted incremented twice, but it only changed from `42` to `43`. So you should have used a kind of locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the code should give you your answer... instead of `while(true)` write `for(i=1;1<1e6;i++)` , write the result to screen and run it.

You'll see it does not add up to 2e6, but rather something around 1.2e6. So yes, you need to lock if you want to get out 2e6.

Don't just hypothesize, after that always test and assert.

Comment: The problem is that you can do tests like that and have them work, and then run them on another machine with slower (or just different) hardware and have it fail.

Comment: That's true (I know from experience), this case however is simple enough to demonstrate the result even on simple architectures.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just *assigning* an `int`, then no. But here you're not just assigning. You're incrementing. So you need some kind of synchronization.

In you want to increment, use [Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx):

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref _test);
```

Comment: Does this also create a memory fence or something to guarantee that the value of `_test` isn't stale? The documentation says it's atomic, but I don't think atomic implies synchronized. (I'm not very familiar with the CLR's memory model.)

Comment: @DaoWen Yes, it will add the appropriate memory barriers.  Atomic means that, at any instant in time you can only observe that the action has either happened, or it hasn't.  A non-atomic operation means that it's possible to observe some partially-complete state in which it has started doing something but not finished.  One way (but not the only way) to achieve atomicity is through synchronization.

Comment: @Servy - What I meant by "I don't think atomic implied synchronized" is that you can atomically apply an operation like _increment_ to a stale value cached by the current thread. I guess it wouldn't make much sense to provide a library routine that did something like that though.

Comment: @Servy I think another way of phrasing the question is "do you need to declare `_test` as `volatile` to use the `Interlocked` functions on them?" (I don't know the answer)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No, you do not.

Comment: `Interlocked.Increment` resolves to the Windows `InterlockedIncrement` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx. That documentation states: "This function generates a full memory barrier (or fence) to ensure that memory operations are completed in order."

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember the thread could also be looking at a stale copy, by locking you assure that the version of the variable you are looking at is being refreshed

When I first started coding and thought that maybe I don't need the freshest copy of the variable I would get stuck in infinite loops because I assume the variable would be updated eventually, but if the variable was cached then it would never update

I included examples with brief descriptions, don't worry about the way the thread is started, that is not relevant

```
private static bool _continueLoop = true;
private static readonly object _continueLoopLock = new object();

private static void StopLoop() 
{ 
    lock(_continueLoopLock) 
        _continueLoop = false;
}

private static void ThreadALoopWillGetStales()
{
    while(_continueLoop)
    {
        //do stuff
        //this is not guaranteed to end
    }
}

private static void ThreadALoopEventuallyCorrect()
{
    while(true)
    {
        bool doContinue;

        lock(_continueLoopLock)
            doContinue = _continueLoop;

        if(!doContinue)
            break;

        //do stuff
        //this will sometimes result in a stale value
        //but will eventually be correct
    }
}

private static void ThreadALoopAlwaysCorrect()
{
    while(true)
    {
        bool doContinue;

        lock(_continueLoopLock)
           if(!_continueLoop)
            break;

        //do stuff
        //this will always be correct
    }
}

private static void ThreadALoopPossibleDeadlocked()
{
     lock(_continueLoopLock)
         while(_continueLoop)
         {
             //if you only modify "_continueLoop"
             //after Acquiring "_continueLoopLock"
             //this will cause a deadlock 
         }
}

private static void StartThreadALoop()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((o)=>{ThreadALoopWillGetStales();});
}
private static void StartEndTheLoop()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o)=>
    {
       //do stuff
       StopLoop();
    });
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartThreadALoop();
    StartEndTheLoop();
}
```

when you start the loop there is a chance that you will continue to get a stale copy of the variable, that is why you **do** need some sort of synchronization when accessing a across multiple threads

Comment: Even if you synchronize you could still get a stale copy, for your example you need to declare `_continueLoop` as [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (In fact in your example the lock is unnessary as assignment operations for bool's are atomic.)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you don't need to do that in all cases

Comment: Yes, but in your case, the lock provides no benefit and you don't get the "freshness" that you claim.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I was providing OP a way to get the same desired effects (eventually having the correct variable) that is guaranteed to work, when I have used volatile in the past it was at best fickle and at worst did not work at all so I try to avoid it. I included an example that is always has a fresh copy of the variable.